# How to navigate from terminal back to code in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, intellij-14

I'm on a mac. I can move from my code to the embedded terminal with F12 (das keyboard), but I can't figure out how to go back to the code? Is there a "last window" key or window selection key?

workflow:

- write some code
- F12 to jump to terminal
- run tests
- < Hit Key > to jump back to code
- ...repeat...

Also, any suggestions on a hotkeys to view shortcuts would be helpful too.

Note: escape and F12 (again) does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/working-with-embedded-local-terminal.html

Press alt+f12 to jump between the terminal window and the edit buffer. Alternatively, you can press CTRL+SHIFT+W to close the terminal window, and that will get you back to the edit buffer.